# How to fit list of numpy array into LSTM Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am new to Keras so I really appreciate any help here. For my project, I am trying to train the neural network on multiple time series. I got it work by running a for loop through to fit each time series to the model. The code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(train)):
    history = model.fit(train_X[i], train_Y[i], epochs=20, batch_size=6, verbose=0, shuffle=True)
```

If I am not wrong, I am doing online training here. Now I'm trying to do batch training to see if the result is better. I tried to fit a list consisting of all timeseries (each converted into a numpy array), but I get this error:

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 56 arrays:
```

Here is the info about the dataset and the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,16),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 1)              72        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 1)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 74
Trainable params: 74
Non-trainable params: 0

print(len(train_X), train_X[0].shape, len(train_Y), train_Y[0].shape)

56 (1, 23, 16) 56 (1, 23, 1)
```

Here is the block of code that gives me the error :

```
pyplot.figure(figsize=(16, 25))
history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False, batch_size = len(train_X))
```

Comment: can you please tell no. of timesteps and and no. of features ? Also why any reason why are you using `flatten` layer?

Comment: @krishna thanks for helping. 23 time steps and 16 features. Using flatten layer because I wanted one single output.

Answer (score 0):

Input shape of LSTM should be - `batch_size`, `timesteps`, `features`.But we need not to mention `batch_size` in input shape if you want you can use `batch_input_shape`.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(23,16),return_sequences=True))
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


X = np.random.random((56,1, 23, 16)) 
y = np.random.random((56,1, 23, 1))
X=np.squeeze(X,axis =1) #as input shape should be (`batch_size`, `timesteps`, `features`)
y = np.squeeze(y,axis =1)
model.fit(X,y,epochs=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False, batch_size = len(X))
```

I am not sure if it serves your purpose.

Comment: i don't think that solves the problem. I have a list of 56 time series.  I am trying to fit the list into the model. I am also looking into doing a fit generator to do batch training, but that does not work as well.

Comment: @DavidLuong what do you mean by '56' time series? can you elaborate a bit. Also fit_generator is used when data can't be fit into memory, if that's not the case there is no point to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry for not elaborating more. So we have data  of 56 different people, each was observed with 16 features in two years. I guess the question here is there is any way we can fit a batch of 7 to train the neural network? Thank you for your help. @krishna

Comment: sorry I'm not able to understand. I'd advise if you want a better solution on this forum post question as comprehensive as possible, that will help people to understand problem better, and many will turn up to help you.

Comment: I apologize, this is all a new topic to me, so It is hard for me to explain it. . What in particular are you confused about? I will try my best to explain it.

Comment: sorry. I'm also a novice, it'll take probably more time for you to make me understand than framing a  new better question.